# Can't pass relative img src route in React + Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I can't dynamically pass relative img src route in React + Webpack with this.props.

This is a very simplified part of the parent component. It iterates some data list and generates ImgComponents passing props. Here is only tiny part of it:

```
return (
      <div>
        <ImgComponent srcProp={videolist.anotherImage.src} />
      </div>
    );
```

The ImgComponent  has:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <img src={`${this.props.srcProp}`} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

In console I get exactly the same route as i pass with this.props.srcProp, but it would not find the folder and the img there. As if webpack does not load the img.
Here is the console:

```
<img src="framework/assets/images/cover-bigbuckbunny.png" class="_2WcF9ZmcK-9bQX6jKk18Y_" data-reactid=".0.1.1:$comedy.0.0.$0.0.0.0">
```

No matter what route i indicate, the img is never found in the folder.

Here is the webpack config for png:

```
{ test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?mimetype=image/png" }
```

BTW. It works fine if i require the file, like:

```
<img src={require ('framework/assets/images/cover-bigbuckbunny.png')} />
```

or indicate some remote route, like `http://route.to.some.img`

Seems like webpack does not load it. What should i do to dynamically load local img files by dynamically passing src with {this.props.src} ? As I can see, the loader loads img fine if i indicate the file with require. But this way i cannot do it dynamically, as require does not take variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I managed to do is to `require('../../assets/images/myFirst.img')` in the object, containing the routs to the locally stored files:

in    `playlist.js`

```
export default (
  {
    cartoons: [{
        images: {
        poster: require('../../assets/images/myFirst.png')
      },
      streams: [{
        type: 'mp4',
        url: 'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4'
      }]
    });
```

Then I work with this list as with any object:

```
import playlist from '../../playlist';
```

and iterate this object in a usual manner. The image will be there.

Comment: How do you do if these urls coming from db?

Comment: I did not try this. I guess would answer it if I could try, but I am quite far from it now.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried importing the entire folder and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Webpack will not traverse your code to find and convert all possible references to files.

Consider following code:

```
<img src={'/foo/bar/baz.jpg'} />
```

It is your responsibility (perhaps using a build target) to ensure that `baz.jpg` is copied into the `foo/bar` directory under your web app root.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, Amey. Does it mean that there is no way for me to do <img src={this.props.src} /> ?

Comment: Even if i write <img src={'/dist/cover.png'} /> and make sure that the file is in the folder, it is not seen. Tried all the possible routes. Seems like inlined src does not work. Do not know what to do.

Comment: I figured it out and placed my answer.